# Laravel 4 equivilant of if isset..?

Tags: laravel-4

I find myself doing this sort of thing a lot.

```
$somevar = isset($someothervar) ? $someothervar : '';
```

I was watching a video or read in a tutorial or something...I don't remember where it was...but at some point I saw something and though, oh wow, that would handle that for me so I don't have use that long line every time...nice!

It seemed like it was something in Laravel that was specifically meant for that, but for the life of me I can't find it now.

Any info on that would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually wrote a tutorial on this last week some time. You can use the "or" statement which cuts it down, bearing in mind that I think this can only be used in Blade templates.

Check out their docs here...
http://laravel.com/docs/templates

And my little tutorial on it...
http://michaelbrooks.co.uk/post/nice-little-laravel-tip

EDIT: Also, the operator you're trying to use is called ternary operators. If you had searched "Laravel ternary" then you would have found this nice little bit of code. :)

Comment: So it just a Blade/views thing?  I was thinking there was something like that I could use from within a model or controller..??

Comment: I'm afraid that it is Blade only. I think ternary operators are the fastest and cleanest way for if/else within controllers and models and they therefore haven't created anything for this. But I would talk to the Laravel community and see if they want to add this in for controllers and models as well. :)

Comment: When using ternary operators try using `empty()` instead of `isset()` where available since `isset()` checks if a variable is set but does not check if it is empty or not.